# OpenGL Interleaved VBOs stride and offset

Tags: java, opengl, vbo

I am making this program that needs to render colored quads.
I am using VBOs for this.

*This is how I store the data for the vertices and the colors:*

**render quad:**

```
 buff.put(3 floats color)
 render the quad (3 floats per vertex * 4 per face * 6 per quad)
```

Now as you see my aim is to use interleaved VBOs but I cant figure out the stride and offset.

**Here are my calls when rendering:**

(Note im using mapped vbos thats why there is no actual data binding):

```
        glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, etn.getVboHandel());
        glBufferDataARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, etn.getVboData().capacity() << 2, GL_STATIC_DRAW_ARB);

        glColorPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, /* stride **/6 << 2, /* offset **/0); 
        glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, /* stride **/6 << 2, /* offset **/0);

        glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0,  etn.getVboData().capacity());
```

I cant get the offset and stride to be correct so when I render I see this weird artifacts..

Comment: There's too much missing information here to be able to answer the question. It's not clear what it is that you're trying to do. For example, what does "3 floats color" mean? Also, stop using the ARB suffixed stuff. Buffer objects are GL 1.5 functionality; they've been core OpenGL for over a *decade*.

Comment: I removed the ARB stuff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stride is how much space is between two tuples and the offset is how much space is between 0 and the first appearance of the first tuple

eg for triangles with 3 floats per position and then 3 floats for normal it looks like this

```
glVertexAttribPointer(0,3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 24, 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(1,3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 24, (GLvoid*) (sizeof(float)*3));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
```

So your vertex pointer has an offset of 0 (assuming that the first three entries are positions) and a stride of 24 (assuming that your vertex color comes directly after the vertex positon)

for the color pointer the offset will be `(GLvoid*) (sizeof(float)*3)` as three GLfloats before the first color triple

This all assumes that your interleaved array is built like this

VVVCCCVVVCCCVVVCCC and so on

For a very simple example in C++ using a model having only vertex and normal information as well as faces, you can check this code out: http://www.incentivelabs.de/Sourcecode/OpenGL10.zip

Comment: The thing is a quad cant have more than 1 different color meaning i only need 1 color for every 4*6 vertex calls so its built like this:
VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVC

Comment: I am not quite sure, but the color has to be set per vertex not per quad.
if the quad (which is a plane in OpenGL) has a different color for each vertex, the color will be interpolated on the plane. The same for triangles. So if your quad should have only one color, every vertex on for the quad needs the same color.

Comment: Ohhhh ok thanks! can you help me with what the other guy said about the capacity?

Comment: Capacity is just how much entries are in the collection

Answer (score 3):

Your description is not really consistent: 3 floats per vertex are not enough to describe a 3D position and a RGB color. YOur code suggests that you actually have 6 values per vertex, so the buffer might look like

```
    +0    +4    +8    +12   +16   +20
 0: pos.x pos.y pos.z col.r col.g col.b
24: pos.x pos.y pos.z col.r col.g col.b
...
```

The stride is the "distance" of two consecutive values of the same attribute, so in this case, it is - as you correctly set -
6*sizeof(GLfloat). The offset is the byte offset of the attribute relative to the start of the buffer. In my example, it is 0 for pos and 3*sizeof(GLfloat) for col. You are setting both to the same offset, so you use the same data for different attributes, which is seldom a good idea.

Also, your buffer setup seems unclear. The line

```
glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0,  etn.getVboData().capacity());
```

suggests that `etn.getVboData().capacity()` is the number of vertices in the buffer. If so,

```
glBufferDataARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, etn.getVboData().capacity() << 2, GL_STATIC_DRAW_ARB);
```

is clearly wrong, since you need 6*sizeof(GLfloat) bytes per vertex, so you copy only parts of the data, and you are accessing out-ouf-buffer data, which is undefined behavior and could result in all kinds of strange effects.

Comment: I dont understand the part about the capacity.. can you explain it further and use java refrences because there is no sizeof in java

Comment: @gopgop: Say you have N vertices, and, as in your case, you need 6 floats (=24 bytes when tightly packed) per vertex, your buffer have a total size of N*24 bytes. `glDrawArrays` expects the number of vertices. So either, `etn.getglDrawArraysVboData().capacity()` is your vertex count, than the `glDrawArrays` call is correct but the `glBufferData` one isn't, or `etn.getglDrawArraysVboData().capacity()` refers to the size of the buffer in bytes, than both oth the lines are wrong, as there should be `capacity()/24` vertices in the buffer (and you upload four times as much data as actually present)

Comment: But when I times it by 24 in bufferData it does not work i get a bunch of artifacts

Comment: @gopgop: As I said: **If** `capacity()` is the number of vertices. My guess would be that it actually is the size of the buffer, in bytes.

Comment: K thanks! Btw I switched to using VAOs and glVetrexAttribPointers and the color doesnt work.. Can you use Mapped VBOs and VAOs together?